# jquery elastic animation doesn't complete

Tags: jquery, anythingslider, elasticlayout

http://www.thebraproject.com/collection

If you slide the clothesline backwards every third item stops dead without completing the elastic animation.  Can anyone see why that might be happening?

I'm using the AnythingSlider for jQuery to make it work.

Comment: That is a very cool use of AnythingSlider! But yeah I can't see why the easing isn't working - very odd. I just answered your other question about updating AnythingSlider and maybe using the update method might fix this problem?

Comment: doesn't appear to be broken, but just to be sure, can you post the code used to render the animation?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Tested with Chrome 9, FireFox 3 and Internet Explorer 8. In which browser does this occur ?

Comment: A little note, I recommend not having the image overlap the arrow. Besides that I can't reproduce.

Comment: I can reproduce it in IE, Safari and FF. Chrome works fine. No anser though, sorry.

Comment: I can't reproduce this either - FF Chrome Safari. Maybe this has something to do with the performace of your computer (lots of javascript on site - causing slowdown)?

Comment: Just an update... this problem should have been fixed in AnythingSlider version 1.5.8+

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe the problem is that the way the slider counts when you go forward and backward it is thinking it is the beginning of the slider and not running the transition.  Try changing your third case

```
case 3:
 var previous_index = 2;
 var next_index = 1;
 break;
```

what happens if you change the next_index variable? Does that fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The easing breaks every time AnythingSlider is forced to "rotate" its pages. (Put another way: any time the item being moved to is a "li.cloned", the easing is broken.)

It looks to me like this is a bug within AnythingSlider, I think some of the animation-complete callbacks are being called without waiting for animation to actually complete.

I hesitate to analyze any further because the current site is using version 1.2 of AnythingSlider, latest version is v1.5.x. I would try upgrading and see if that fixes your problem.

https://github.com/ProLoser/AnythingSlider/downloads

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that any item that stopped without completing the animation continues to behave in that manner even if its not the third item the next time you slide them backwards. Other items that finished the animation when sliding backwards initially, complete their animation the next time you slide backwards even if they are the third item. So whatever is going wrong is going wrong the first time you slide backwards I think. Hope this helps if you haven't already fixed this.